# using lambda to extract the number expected

Tags: pandas

Happy New Year all,
I have a list of numberphone got from an another function , however , it still exist a lot of unexpected number , sth like below:

['0355198232', '0963.297.187', '0355198232', '0355198232', '000099772009', '0355198232']

the unexpected is `'000099772009'` , i tried to wrote the function to do this

```
a = '0098475634859'
b = '0903.164.570'
def isphone(num):
    if len(num) > 10:
        if re.findall('[ .]',num):
            return num
df['Phone Number 2'] = df['Phone Number'].apply(lambda x: isphone(str(x)))
```

This function work correctly with "a" , "b" variable, however when i applied it into the dataframe with lambda ,it seems that not work well. Can someone please help assist?
update my lab :
I have dataframe with column "Phone Number" like below:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `that not work well`? Please provide expected and actual results.

Comment: What does lambda have to do with anything here?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg , I have updated my dataframe, I want to add the new column "Phone Number 2" which get data from the column "Phone Number" except number that more than have lengh > 10 and without "space" or "."  . sth like "000099772009" , "994523901293"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , I have update the photo to describe for the lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot, it looks like you have lists of phone numbers in "Phone Number" column, so you could try this:

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Phone Number": [
            [
                "0355198232",
                "0963.297.187",
                "0355198232",
                "0355198232",
                "000099772009",
                "0355.198.232",
            ],
        ]
    }
)

df["Phone Number 2"] = df["Phone Number"].apply(
    lambda x: [isphone(str(phone)) for phone in x]
)
```

And then:

```py
print(df["Phone Number"][0])
# ['0355198232', '0963.297.187', '0355198232', '0355198232', '000099772009', '0355.198.232']

print(df["Phone Number 2"][0])
# [None, '0963.297.187', None, None, None, '0355.198.232']
```